# Local Binary Pattern rotation

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision

Sorry for the question but I want to know how LBP works so that I can prepare for my exam, To do that, I decided to calculate by hand for the matrix but the problem is about the rotation pixel over the image based on the radius and neighbor of LBP, I do it clockwise and top most left then top most right, .... but the result is still different from the result in "skimage" lib

With the example like this:

```
             [[5, 4, 2, 2, 1],
              [3, 5, 8, 1, 3],
              [2, 5, 4, 1, 2],
              [4, 3, 7, 2, 7],
              [1, 4, 4, 2, 6]]
```

and with `rad=2, n=8, method='ror'` :

I try make it by hand with `p(2,2) = 4` is:

```
             [[ 5    2    1 ]
              [ 2    4    2 ]
              [ 3    4    2 ]]
```

so it may be is:     `12243252 -> 00010010?`

Otherwise, The result is in skimage:

```
              [[  1.   3.   7.   3.   7.]
              [  7.   0.   0.  31.   5.]
              [ 15.   0.   9. 127.  15.]
              [  3.   3.   5.  23.   1.]
              [  7.   3.   5.  13.   0.]]
```

and code is:

```py
from skimage import feature
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = np.array([[5, 4, 2, 2, 1],
                  [3, 5, 8, 1, 3],
                  [2, 5, 4, 1, 2],
                  [4, 3, 7, 2, 7],
                  [1, 4, 4, 2, 6]])

radius = 2
neighbors = 8
lbp_result = feature.local_binary_pattern(image, neighbors, radius, 'ror')


plt.subplot(1, 2, 1), plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Original Image')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2), plt.imshow(lbp_result, cmap='gray'), plt.title('LBP Image (r=2, 8 directions)')


print(image)
print()
print(lbp_result)
plt.show()
```

Can anyone help me with this, please? And by the way, how to rotate if the `r > 2` and `neighbor > 8`?Thank you so much for helping me.